# Prepending text to input using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am looking to add country codes to a phone number based on the selection of a dropdown. So far I have:

```
jQuery(function($) {
var input = $( "#Phone" );
var country = "";
$('#Country').on('change', function() {
  var inputval = input.val();
  if ($(this).val() == "United States") {
    country = "1 ";
    input.val(country + inputval);
  } else if($(this).val() == "United Kingdom"){
    country = "+44 ";
    input.val(country + inputval);
  }
});
});
```

It will update the number yes but if I switch from US to UK it keeps the 1 or +44.

Comment: _“but if I switch from US to UK it keeps the 1 or +44”_ – well of course it does, because you modified the input value. So you would either need to explicitly remove the previously added prefix first, or store the “original” value. But why do you need to manipulate the value inside that input field in the first place? If the user selected the prefix in a dropdown field, then you already _have_ the info you need - so what is the redundancy good for anyway?

Comment: You can use just different fields for code and number

Comment: I think the best solution would be to have a separate disabled input only for the code. 

Else you can store the phone number without any code and update the display according to the selected country but it won't work if the user updates the phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this;

HTML template;

```
<select id="country">
   <option value="+91"> India </option>
   <option value="+1"> USA </option>
   .....
</select>
```

Consider the input field for phone number is like:

```
<input type="number" id="phone">
```

Now the JS;

```
var phone="";
var prefix="";
$("#phone").keyup(function(){
     phone=$(this).val().replace(prefix,"");
})

$("#country").change(function(){
    $("#phone").val($(this).val()+phone);
    prefix=$(this).val();

    /* explanation
     * setting the value of  $("#phone")
     * concatenating  $(this).val() [basically the select] and the value of
     * $("#phone") itself which is stored in phone variable
     */

})
```

Comment: I don't think that will work. If you change the country two times. You'll be back in the case where you have +1+91 before the phone number.

Comment: It's better but imagine you have a country selected, your phone number may be : +91011112, you update it because you make a mistake with the last digit : +91011113. Now the var phone contains the +91 as well so you are still stuck.

Comment: The issue with this is I already have a value attached to the value.

Comment: Solved it @Nico

Comment: Yes it works perfectly now (you just have to make the input #phone of type text because of the "+") but it's the best solution so far! +1

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Modified example to work with just a single entry and keeping phone number while you change country code:

https://jsfiddle.net/ryqxpwst/1/

How about this approach: Have an entry for the country code and a different entry for the phone number (you can combine both before the form is submitted if absolutely necessary):

```
jQuery(function($) {
var input = $( "#Phone" );
var ccode = $('#ccode');
var country = "";
$('#Country').on('change', function() {
  console.log('change..' + $("#Country option:selected").val() );
  var inputval = input.val();
  ccode.val($("#Country option:selected").val());  
});
});
```

Working Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ryqxpwst/

Hope it helps!